# Can the size of the error log in Eclipse be increased?

Tags: eclipse, error-log

I use the error log view in Eclipse quite often to track behaviour during debug, but when I log a large amount of things (the limit is currently 50), they fall off the edge and I have to dive into the text file version of the log.

Is there any way to increase the size of the error log?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

YOu can set the eclipse.log.size.max property in your config.ini
By default it should be set to 1000 lines though

http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fmisc%2Fruntime-options.html

Is that the logfile you need?

Edit - for the error log, the number is controlled by the filter option.
Select 'filters...' from the error log drop down menu, then change the number of lines in the 'limit visible events to:' which defaults to 50.

Comment: I'm afraid this hasn't helped. The eclipse.log.size.max property only applies to the file, as far as I can tell. I am referring to the 'Error Log' view in the Eclipse UI

Comment: Select the error log drop down box (the one on the right of the log), select 'filters...' and then change the 'limit visible events to' to something other than 50

Comment: YES! Thanks. I'm at a loss as to why I didn't think to look at Filters

Comment: I don't think it is actually that obvious, but I saw it there looking for something else. But then most things on eclipse aren't that obvious!

Answer (score 0):

window - preferences - java - compiler - building : Maximum number of problems reported per compilation unit (increase from 100 (default) to desired)